# JQuery: Reading the JSON response of the server

Tags: jquery, json

OK, I have this piece of code,

```
var record = new Object(); //var aData = {};でもOK  
record["deviceID"] = "123456"; //aData["name"] = "hoge"でもoK  
$.getJSON("http://192.168.2.10:8080/commapi/comaction/init", {record: JSON.stringify(record)},
function(objRes){  
    alert(objRes["response"]); //objRes["country"]でもok  
});
```

I just made a simple servlet that simply replies back the deviceID I put. But my problem is there is an error like

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.2.10:8080/commapi/comaction/init?record=%7B%22deviceID%22%3A%22123456%22%7D. Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

how can I fix this? Thank you!

**UPDATED SCRIPT**
I tried using the JSONP, and my resulting script looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ui-2").click(function(){
      getJSON("http://192.168.2.143:8080/commapi/comaction/init?record=%7B%  22deviceID%22%3A%22123456%22%7D&callback=loaded"); 
  });
};


function getJSON(url){
var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.setAttribute('src',url);
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);

  // Loading ..
  $("results").innerHTML = '<p>Loading &hellip;</p>'; 
};


function loaded(data) { 

var res = data.query.results.item;
var html = "";
var i =  0;
var y = res.length;

for(i; i<y; i++) { 
    alert(data.deviceID);
} 

};
```

but this is the new error
    Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json.

Comment: try without the `http://` part like `$.getJSON("192.168.2.10:8080/commapi/comaction/init",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are not allowed to do `Cross-site HTTP requests` from JavaScript. That is, you are only allowed to make AJAX requests to your own requestee domain only.

You can only be successful with `http://192.168.2.10:8080/commapi/comaction/init` AJAX call if the AJAX call is made from the same domain as `http://192.168.2.10:8080`.

As a workaround, this is often accomplished by `JSONP` which passes a `JavaScript callback function` which is a JavaScript function located on your page and requests to the server where the server wraps the `JSON` data with callback function. This is executed by creating a `<script></script>` tag with `src` attribute to be the `AJAX` url and appended to the HTML `body`.

PS: You server must have capability to wrap your output data which will require to change on your `http://192.168.2.10:8080/commapi/comaction/init` codes.

Comment: thanks for youwr reply. i tried JSONP (which is the first time i heard about it) and there is another error like "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json." is this problem on the server side? I dont know exactly what kind of data should i send back to my client to make this work

Comment: Please [read this](http://blog.altosresearch.com/supporting-the-jsonp-callback-protocol-with-jquery-and-java/) article and I believe it will help you to get started. The example comes with Java on the server and jQuery on client side.

Comment: thanks! that was so helpful. solved everything! thanks thanks thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That is due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) in other words, host and port should be same.

To work around it, have a look at [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP).

[Here is a resouce to get you started.](http://www.vcarrer.com/2010/11/about-jsonp-in-javascript.html)

Comment: thanks for youwr reply. i tried JSONP (which is the first time i heard about it) and there is another error like "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/json." is this problem on the server side? I dont know exactly what kind of data should i send back to my client to make this work